# gcc returns "undefined reference to" function after editing library source code

Tags: c

- I have added a function inside the .c source code of a certain library and added the function header in the corresponding .h file then installed the whole program (./configure ; make ; make install) with no error.
- checked with **nm** if my function was present inside the shared library (.so) (generated by the compilation above) : it said the function was there
- when compiling a program calling my custom function and linking it against the library , I get the following error:

> ```
> $ gcc -o test test.c -lnftables
> /tmp/cc47BbcQ.o: In function `main':
> test.c:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to print_hello()
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

- But when compiling a program without any reference to my custom function, it works and runs with no error.

system: Debian 9 stretch

RAM: 8GB

CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz

library: nftables 9.4 (source [here](https://netfilter.org/projects/nftables/downloads.html#nftables-0.9.4))

gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516

Comment: You should include the output of the `nm` invocation, limiting it to the definition of the function. I'm guessing that the type being reported will be `t`, rather than `T` - i.e. local to the library, and not exported

Comment: @Petesh: you are right

`# nm /usr/local/lib/libnftables.so |grep print_hello
0000000000042df0 t print_hello`

What should I do then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nftables library only makes specific things externally usable. It's accomplished with two mechanisms:

- default visibility
- mapfiles

A little bit of reading of the source indicates that the documented mechanism for controlling the visibility is a declaration of:

```
EXPORT_SYMBOL(routine);
```

which is defined in the `utils.h` file into the source file. So if you add a:

```
EXPORT_SYMBOL(print_hello);
```

either in the `./src/libnftables.c`, or in the file you declared the the `print_hello` (ensuring that you've included `utils.h` in that file), should cover the visibility.

The second thing is the mapfile, which defines the agreed upon interface of the `.so`, and this is in the `libnftables.map` file. You would also need to add the `print_hello` export to this file, in the `global:` section in order to have it exported into the API of the library.

Comment: thank you @Petesh
the EXPORT_SYMBOL macro was definitely the solution.